# YouTube only needs one spam flag to remove a video

Tags: youtube

In YouTube there is the option to flag a video, using the report feature below the video

[image: Report icon]

In the help section it is stated that

> If you see a video that you know is spam, based on our Terms of Use and/or Community Guidelines, you can report it to us for review by clicking the "Flag" link under the video. Then follow the steps below:
>
> - Move your cursor over the "Select a reason" drop-down to see our flag menu
> - Click "Spam" as the reason for flagging
> - Click the "Flag This Video" button to report the video
> - The video will then be reviewed by our staff.

So I reported a video based on affiliate links, I assumed it would take a few days or the flag even rejected or at the very least be based on numerous other flags as well.

[image: Reporting]

The video was immediately removed

[image: TOS removal]

Before it looked like

[image: Video before]

What's the reasoning/logic for such a speedy action, it doesn't seem that the flag was actually reviewed. **Is this a bug or will I able to kill videos with the single click of a button?**

Comment: Maybe it was just blocked for you. Do you still have the URL? I tried - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6tVb50c-3Y (which looks like the URL in your screenshot) and got a "This video is unavailable" message, which appears to be the general 404 error.

Comment: @ChrisF yes that is the url, it seems it shows that message when I'm not logged in as well. I'll update to what it looked like before

Comment: I'm assuming the video had already picked up few spam flags? Your flag might have triggered the point at which the video got acted upon

Comment: NOTE: I got the URL wrong. It should be **S0c** not **50c**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming that the video in question is this one? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6tVbS0c-3Y

Which I see as being removed for violating the terms of service.

I am guessing that either:

- Your flag was immediately reviewed and upheld

Or

- Certain flags, such as spam flags, mean the video is automatically removed. Once reviewed by a member of the YouTube team I presume it can either be reinstated or left as being removed.

It does seem *really* efficient if your flag was reviewed immediately but not impossible. The YouTube help documentation does state that any flagged videos are [reviewed promptly 24 hours a day, 7 days a week.](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&selected=report_content&page=troubleshooter.cs&ctx=vidcomplaint_report_content_55777&problem=vidcomplaint)

> When YouTube users identify inappropriate content, as described in our
>   [Terms of Use](http://www.youtube.com/t/terms) and [Community Guidelines](http://www.youtube.com/t/community_guidelines), they are able to flag the
>   video. Each flagged video is promptly reviewed by YouTube
>   administrators (24 hours a day, 7 days a week) who immediately remove
>   any content that violates the Terms of Use.

Comment: Ah. I got a "5" rather than an "S" in my URL.